# Networkx python all_simple_paths returns path in (u, v, key) format

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I am working on python 3 and networkx 2.0. For enumerating all simple paths between 2 nodes, I am using [`nx.all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths).

My graph is an undirected multigraph, [`nx.MultiGraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html). Unfortunately, `nx.all_simple_paths` enumerates all the paths *without* including the edge key value. So it is not possible to distinguish easily between paths containing different parallel edges.

```
edge = [(1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), (2,3,1), (2,3,2)]
g = nx.MultiGraph()
g.add_edges_from(edge)
for path in map(nx.utils.pairwise, nx.all_simple_paths(g,1,3)):     
    print(list(path))
```

Output for the above snippet is: (u, v)

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

But the desired output is: (u, v, key)

```
[(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1)]
[(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2)]
[(1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1)]
[(1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2)]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1)]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2)]
```

---

The reason why I would like the key value is that it would make my subsequent computations more efficient for mapping the corresponding edges.

I also tried to add key values while searching as follows:

```
def all_simple_paths(G, source=1, target=3, cutoff=(len(g) - 1)):
    if cutoff < 1:
        return
    visited = []
    for src, _, key in G.edges(source, keys=True):
        visited.append((src,key))
        stack = [((v, key) for u, v, key in G.edges(source, keys=True))]
        # print(list(stack))
        while stack:
            children = stack[-1]
            # print('children: ')
            child = next(children, None)
            # print(child)
            if child is None:
                # print('pop happened!')
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()
            elif len(visited) < cutoff:
                # print('visited <cutoff: ')
                # print(visited)
                # print(list(child)[0])
                if child[0] == target:
                    # print('child is target')
                    print(visited + [target])
                    yield visited + [target]
                elif child not in visited:
                    # print("child not in visited")
                    visited.append(child)
                    # print(visited)
                    stack.append(((v, k) for u, v, k in G.edges(child, keys=True)))
            else:  # len(visited) == cutoff:
                # print('at cutoff')
                count = ([child] + list(children)).count(target)
                # print('count: ')
                # print(count)
                count = 1            # Dynamic count is not working
                for i in range(count):
                    # print(visited + [target])
                    yield visited + [target]
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()
```

Output of the modified program (between nodes 1 and 3) is:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), 3]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), 3]
[(1, 1), (2, 3), 3]
[(1, 2), (2, 1), 3]
[(1, 2), (2, 2), 3]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), 3]
[(1, 3), (2, 1), 3]
[(1, 3), (2, 2), 3]
[(1, 3), (2, 3), 3]
```

The output is still not perfect. The key of edge 3 (refer the above output) is still missing and the `count` attribute in len(visited) == cutoff" is not dynamic (by default it returns 0)

Comment: @rodgdor I tried modifying the nx.all_simple_paths algo. My idea was to include edge's key values when enumerating the graph.

Comment: @ArunKumar what is the output coming in the second case?

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar I have modified the question with the current script and output. I am pretty close, missing out on something very basic. Would be very thankful, if you could pinpoint it out!

Comment: well let's look at MultiDiGraph as extenstion of DiGraph. If nx.all_simple_paths finds a path including an edge (u,v) it means there is a path for all the edges in (u,v,*) so you can simply iterate for each (u,v) edge in MultiDiGraph.

Comment: I think you need to use nx.all_simple_edge_paths(). to get the output you desire.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output simply use nx.all_simple_**edge**_paths instead of nx.all_simple_paths

```
import networkx as nx

edge = [(1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), (2,3,1), (2,3,2)]
g = nx.MultiGraph()
g.add_edges_from(edge)
for path in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(g,1,3):
    print(path)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1)]
[(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2)]
[(1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1)]
[(1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2)]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1)]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2)]
```